# How to store the scraped data properly in 2 servers with Scrapy ?

Tags: python, ftp, scrapy

I use Scrapy and i want to export the items in 2 servers.

I use

```
scrapy crawl spiderName -s FEED_URI=ftp://usr:pass@host:port/path/to/folder-ftp/allITems.csv
```

it works for one **FEED_URI**, but I need to store the results in 2 different servers, I tried :

```
scrapy crawl spiderName -s FEED_URI=ftp://usr:pass@host:port/path/to/folder-ftp/allITems.csv  -s FEED_URI=ftp://usr2:pas2s@host2:port2/path/to/folder-ftp/allITems.csv
```

but It stored just in the second one. How can I export the results in 2 servers ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not supported by default, but it can be done by extending the default`FeedExporter` extension:

```
class FeedExporter(object):

    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings
        self.urifmt = settings['FEED_URI']
        if not self.urifmt:
            raise NotConfigured
```

You may use something like `settings['FEED_URI'].split(';')` to extract a list of `FEED_URIS` from that configuration field. And then replace every use of `self.urifmt` with a loop. For example:

```
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        uri = self.urifmt % self._get_uri_params(spider)
```

Would become:

```
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        for urifmt in self.uriftms:
            uri = urifmt % self._get_uri_params(spider)
            # Rest of the code here
```

Finally, don't forget to disable the default exporter extension and enable the new one:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter': None,
    '{your_project}.{path_to_exporter_file}.{exporter_name}': 1,
}
```